# Why does the symbol of the SHA512 function in libeay32 not have a leading underscore?

Tags: c++, c, linker, openssl, x86-64

I am attempting to use OpenSSL's `SHA512` function in a C++ project of mine. In order to do this, I include `openssl/sha.h` in my source files that call `SHA512` and link with the `libeay32.lib` library.

`SHA512` is declared in `openssl/sha.h` as:

```
extern "C" {
//...
unsigned char *SHA512(const unsigned char *d, size_t n,unsigned char *md);
//...
}
```

When linking, however, the symbol is not found:

```
mysql_sha.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _SHA512 referenced in function _sha512
```

The problem appears to be that in `libeay32.lib`, the symbol for the function is actually `SHA512` (no leading underscore), and I also see `__imp_SHA512` when normally it would be `__imp__SHA512`.

I am using the [Win64 build of OpenSSL 1.0.0d](http://www.slproweb.com/download/Win64OpenSSL-1_0_0d.exe) from Shining Light Productions.

Why would the symbol of the `SHA512` function not have a leading underscore? How do I get around this problem?

Comment: Far too localized a question. More suited for a mailing list.

Comment: I don't agree Shaggy. Why does this question bother you?

Comment: @Shaggy: it's only "localized" in the sense of being specific to Windows. I don't use that platform myself, but I understand it's still quite popular for some reason.

Comment: @TonyK @MikeSeymour it's localized in the sense that someone is asking about a single, specific symbol name, in a specific version of a specific library, for a specific operating system. That's the very definition of localized. This kind of minutiae is much more suited for the mailing list for the project.

Comment: @Shaggy Frog: Note that the OP's question has now been answered, and accepted. I count that as a success for stackoverflow.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There is only one calling convention for 64-bit code.  None of the nonsense of `__cdecl`, `__stdcall`, `__fastcall` etcetera.  Whoever comes up with another x64 calling convention to save a fraction of a nanosecond is going to be summarily executed.  Accordingly, DLL exports no longer have to be decorated with leading underscore and @ characters.  The exported name is just plain SHA512.

Unfortunately, that doesn't explain why your compiler still prefixes an underscore.  Sounds like you're actually using a 32-bit compiler.

Comment: Aha! I was using the Win32 configuration. Thank you for pointing this out.